# Store static function reference to extern C function in global static var: mismatched types: expected fn pointer, found fn item

Tags: rust

I need a global static variable, that references a `extern "C"` function.

I get the following compiler error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:17:28
   |
17 | static BAR: Bar = Bar::new(&foobar);
   |                            ^^^^^^^ expected fn pointer, found fn item
   |
   = note: expected reference `&'static unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !`
              found reference `&unsafe extern "C" fn() -> ! {foobar}`
```

My code down below or on [Rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=af2f35c870d0895c15e62308f20bfc2c)

```rust
extern "C" {
    fn foobar() -> !;
}

struct Bar {
    foo: &'static unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !
}

impl Bar {
    const fn new(foo: &'static unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

static BAR: Bar = Bar::new(&foobar);

fn main() {

}
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Funnily enough, when [you change it a bit](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9d57e4d946aa4152656f4cd932672c97) and add an explicit constant in between, you don't get a type error anymore, but “error[E0658]: function pointers cannot appear in constant functions”

Comment: Also note that in Rust, `fn() -> !` is a type useful by itself, you don't need explicit references to make "function pointers": https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a78ec15c8c829b299483da6ed94e20b3

Answer (score 3):

The `fn` type is already a pointer (called a "function pointer"), so you don't need to put it behind a reference:

```rust
struct Bar {
    foo: unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !,
}
```

It can be created like this:

```rust
impl Bar {
    const fn new(foo: unsafe extern "C" fn() -> !) -> Self {
        Self {
            foo
        }
    }
}

static BAR: Bar = Bar::new(foobar);
```

When you try to compile this, Rust tells you that function pointers in `const` contexts are unstable. By using the *Nightly* channel and enabling the `const_fn_fn_ptr_basics` feature, it works:

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c82e2c6bdfe8ed67b8640c89709b0e9d)

(This is likely to change in the future, don't hesitate to update this answer when needed)